# Extraction and processing the data from txt file

Tags: python, file-io

I am beginner in python (also in programming)I have a larg file containing repeating 3 lines with numbers 1 empty line and again...
if I print the file it looks like:

```
1.93202838
1.81608154
1.50676177

2.35787777 
1.51866227
1.19643624

...
```

I want to take each three numbers - so that it is one vector, make some math operations with them and write them back to a new file and move to another three lines - to another vector.so here is my code (doesnt work):

```
import math
inF = open("data.txt", "r+")
outF =  open("blabla.txt", "w")
a = []
fin = []
b = []

for line in inF:
    a.append(line)
    if line.startswith(" \n"):
        fin.append(b)
        h1 = float(fin[0])
        k2 = float(fin[1])
        l3 = float(fin[2])
        h = h1/(math.sqrt(h1*h1+k1*k1+l1*l1)+1)
        k = k1/(math.sqrt(h1*h1+k1*k1+l1*l1)+1)
        l = l1/(math.sqrt(h1*h1+k1*k1+l1*l1)+1)
        vector = [str(h), str(k), str(l)]
        outF.write('\n'.join(vector)         
    b = a
    a = []

inF.close()
outF.close()
print "done!"
```

I want to get "vector" from each 3 lines in my file and put it into blabla.txt output file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: welcome to SO! This place is for Q&A about programming, other people will not write your code for you, but rather help you fix your own. It's better if you first try to solve this yourself and then come back and show us what you tried!

Comment: Would you please define what "doesn't work" means? Is the result not as expected (then what do you expect), or do you get any error?

Comment: it returns: "error - invalid syntax" on the line where "b = a"

Comment: I found the problem, check my answer below ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 'code comment' answer:

- take care to close all parenthesis, in order to match the opened ones! (this is *very* likely to raise `SyntaxError` ;-) )
- `fin` is created as an empty list, and is never filled. Trying to call any value by `fin[n]` is therefore very likely to break with an `IndexError`;
- `k2` and `l3` are created but never used;
- `k1` and `l1` are not created but used, this is very likely to break with a `NameError`;
- `b` is created as a copy of `a`, so is a list. But you do a `fin.append(b)`: what do you expect in this case by appending (not [*extending*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=extend#more-on-lists)) a list?

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes it helps a lot !! thank you, it works already. I made several additional mistakes on the way, but corrected them already. I changed b = a to b.append(a[0]) and then empty a by a=[].

Answer (score 0):

This is only in the answers section for length and formatting.

[Input and output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

[Control flow](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

I know nothing of vectors, you might want to look into the [Math module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) or [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Those links should hopefully give you all the information you need to at least get started with this problem, as yuvi said, the code won't be written for you but you can come back when you have something that isn't working as you expected or you don't fully understand.